# Spring Boot Error getOutputStream() has already been called for this response after forward

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, basic-authentication, requestdispatcher

I am currently developing a Spring Boot App. I implemented Spring Boot security for httpBasic authentication. When authentication was successful, my custom Filter Method gehts called.

```
protected void onSuccessfulAuthentication(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest request,
        javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse response, Authentication authResult) throws IOException {
Iterator<? extends GrantedAuthority> it = authResult.getAuthorities().iterator();
        switch (it.next().getAuthority()) {
        case (MyConstants.ROLE_USER): {
            try {
                request.getRequestDispatcher("/user/data").forward(request, response);  break;
        } catch (ServletException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
```

So I want to forward the rquest Object with JSON Data I need to my RestController endpoint. 
This works. 
In my Controller I want to return ResponseEntity with Data and Http Status Code.

```
@RequestMapping(value="/upload", consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public ResponseEntity< HttpStatus> upload(@RequestBody String uploadData){

    ResponseEntity<String> httpStatus = sendExchangeToRestApi(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, uploadData,
            "http://localhost:8080/upload", HttpMethod.PUT);
    return new ResponseEntity<String>("Test". HttpStatus.OK);

}
```

I test this with Postman. The output is ok so I get Status 200 and Test in my Body output.
But I run in the following error:

> Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [java.lang.IllegalStateException: getOutputStream() has already been called for this response] with root cause
>   java.lang.IllegalStateException: getOutputStream() has already been called for this response
>       at org.apache.catalina.connector.Response.getWriter(Response.java:582)
>       at org.apache.catalina.connector.ResponseFacade.getWriter(ResponseFacade.java:227)
>       at javax.servlet.ServletResponseWrapper.getWriter(ServletResponseWrapper.java:109)
>       at javax.servlet.ServletResponseWrapper.getWriter(ServletResponseWrapper.java:109)
>       at javax.servlet.ServletResponseWrapper.getWriter(ServletResponseWrapper.java:109)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.util.OnCommittedResponseWrapper.getWriter(OnCommittedResponseWrapper.java:149)
>       at javax.servlet.ServletResponseWrapper.getWriter(ServletResponseWrapper.java:109)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.util.OnCommittedResponseWrapper.getWriter(OnCommittedResponseWrapper.java:149)
>       at org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspWriterImpl.initOut(JspWriterImpl.java:115)
>       at org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspWriterImpl.flushBuffer(JspWriterImpl.java:108)
>       at org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.release(PageContextImpl.java:172)
>       at org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspFactoryImpl.internalReleasePageContext(JspFactoryImpl.java:120)
>       at org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspFactoryImpl.releasePageContext(JspFactoryImpl.java:75)
>       at org.apache.jsp.view.login_jsp._jspService(login_jsp.java:171)
>       at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
>       at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
>       at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:458)
>       at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:386)
>       at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:330)
>       at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:712)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doInclude(ApplicationDispatcher.java:580)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.include(ApplicationDispatcher.java:516)
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView.renderMergedOutputModel(InternalResourceView.java:162)
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:316)
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1370)
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:1116)
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1055)
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:942)
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:998)
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:890)
>       at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:634)
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:875)
>       at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>       at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilterInternal(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:215)
>       at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>       at org.springframework.boot.actuate.web.trace.servlet.HttpTraceFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpTraceFilter.java:90)
>       at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:320)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:127)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:91)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:119)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:137)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:111)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:170)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilterInternal(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:215)
>       at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilterInternal(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:215)
>       at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:200)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:116)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:66)
>       at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:56)
>       at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:215)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:178)
>       at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:357)
>       at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:270)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>       at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99)
>       at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>       at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:92)
>       at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>       at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:93)
>       at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>       at org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.filterAndRecordMetrics(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:154)
>       at org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.filterAndRecordMetrics(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:122)
>       at org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:107)
>       at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>       at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:200)
>       at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:199)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
>       at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:490)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139)
>       at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74)
>       at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
>       at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:408)
>       at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
>       at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:770)
>       at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1415)
>       at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
>       at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

So it seems like getOutputStream()/getWriter() gets called multiple times but I don't know why.

Comment: If you have a question about a specific piece of code not working, that would be a good question to ask, but this question is far too vague to give a good answer. Can you narrow it down?

Comment: Honestly, it doesn't make any sense at all. As there are no actual real-world requirements for this service (at least, you haven't stated any) one can't really decide what is a good idea or not. At it is, it is just a complicated solution for some vague abstract problem.

Comment: I just want to do a simple example to get startet. I neversaid this is a real problem. I was hoping for answers like Burims. I've read many things  about this topic and I just want to have help to get it in context

Comment: @medTech if you are satisfied with my answer please mark it as ANSWER
best ragards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One thing you should be aware of, is that each microservice should have it's own Database, if all of your microservices share the same database, than the DB will become you central Contract and it will be always hard to make changes since you never know which Microservice uses what.

When it comes to RabbitMQ, I personally  think that it is the best Message-Broker ever.
I recommend you to have one Queue/Microservice and one Exchange/Microservice.
Than you can easy configure your RabbitMQ to redirect Messages between queues based on routing key.

Hope this helps
Best Regard

Burim Hajrizaj